# Why gitlab runner is hanging?

Tags: gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I am running my build with gitlab-runner on 24 digital ocean servers. The build still takes a long time (up to 40-50 minutes) because some runners are hanging at the step

```
Running with gitlab-runner 11.5.1 
  on <projectname> build coordinator
```

[image]

How can I prevent gitlab runner from hanging?

Or I need to increase RAM for gitlab runner coordinator (for now is running on 1GB server) because it cannot handle 24 jobs at once?

Maybe I need to split my rspec and cucumber jobs between different coordinators?